# How to address CORS issue in Angular 8 without changing the backend?

Tags: angular, api, cors

I am trying to send a GET request to the backend (https://api.zenefits.com/core/people) from my Angular app which runs on localhost:4200. I have tried many options and read many blog posts but couldn't find anything that works for me. I tried to use the proxy method of solving this problem since I don't have access to the backend but that is still giving me the following CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.zenefits.com/external/people/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4200/core/people') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The following is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  employeeQueryUrl: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.employeeQueryUrl = 'https://api.zenefits.com/core/people';
  }

  getAllEmployees() {
    return this.http.get(
      this.employeeQueryUrl, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          Authorization: 'Bearer elZxQlHDSUallvL3OnnH'})});
  }
}
```

The following is my proxy.conf.json:

```
{
    "/core/*": {
      "target": "https://api.zenefits.com/core/people",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug"
      }
}
```

I have tried many methods but in vain. The docs are not clear on how should the files look. I am not able to understand why the URL has changed to `external/people` instead of `core/people` in the error message too. 
I know there are a lot of similar questions out there but most of them configure the backend and I don't have access to it. The rest are not working for me. So, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your api url to use the proxy (using a relative url), not the api service directly.

Change the following variable to

`this.employeeQueryUrl = '/core/people';`

And your proxy config needs to be updated to

```
{
    "/core/*": {
      "target": "https://api.zenefits.com/",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug"
      }
}
```

Then, your api call will be picked up by the proxy, and redirect all request from `/core/*` to `https://api.zenefits.com/core/*`

Here is the documentation from [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Comment: I followed this but still doesn't solve my problem ;(

Comment: Did you restart your server? I mean, did you terminate your process and run `ng serve` anew?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server and the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you add the following line to your `angular.json` serve - options configurations? `"proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"`?

Comment: I am also wondering, do you want the api call to finally be `https://api.zenefits.com/external/people/` or `https://api.zenefits.com/core/people/`

Comment: Yes, you can check the paste -> https://pastebin.com/edd3fgmD

Comment: The proxy is written as `"proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"` in your paste, is it really the correct location of the file? did you forget to add `src/` to it? -> `"src/proxy.conf.json"`

Comment: I want it to go to `https://api.zenefits.com/core/people/` I don't know why it is redirecting to /external. I looked at the APIs docs (https://developers.zenefits.com/docs/getting-started) but couldn't find any reason.

Comment: Actually it is at the same level as angular.json; I didn't put it inside src/

Comment: Then I am sorry to tell you that I am not sure what is happening :(

Answer (score 1):

You cant remove the CORS error with angular(front-end) itself, you'll need to also address it from backend for sure.

But for the angular part, what you can do is use proxy.config file:

```
{  
 "/api/*": {  
  "target": "http://localhost:57263",  
  "secure": false,  
  "logLevel": "debug"  
 }  
}
```

and add proxy reference to angular.json file.

follow these steps and you'll be good to go(below link addresses the issue for angular+node, for your back-end technology just a google search will do..) 
https://www.techiediaries.com/fix-cors-with-angular-cli-proxy-configuration/

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I am a bit confused about this. You say that it can't be solved by Angular itself, then why post the proxy config? Also the target is the url for the backend right? Or is it something else? Actually these are some details I am getting stuck at which made me post this question.

Comment: I think you should read this post, from where i learnt about CORS.maybe this will help you [link](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b)