# How to enable CORS in angular get requests

Tags: angular, cors

I'm trying to send a get request from [this](https://skysportsapi.herokuapp.com/sky/getnews/football/v1.0/) api using angular but i get an  error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://skysportsapi.herokuapp.com/sky/getnews/football/v1.0/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Here's my ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
const headers= new HttpHeaders()
.set('content-type', 'application/json')
.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.component.css']
})
export class NewsComponent implements OnInit {

  public myNews:any= []
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  
getNews(){
  const url = "https://skysportsapi.herokuapp.com/sky/getnews/football/v1.0/";
  this.http.get(url ,{ 'headers': headers }).subscribe((result)=>{
    this.myNews = result
    console.log(result);
})}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getNews()
  }

}
```

So i went on to make a proxy as suggested and here is my  `proxy.conf.json` file

```
{
    "/sky/*":{
        "target": "https://skysportsapi.herokuapp.com",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/sky": ""
        }
}
}
```

I'm still getting the same error , i wonder what i'm doing wrong .

Comment: You would need to [Proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) to the backend server. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665054/how-to-address-cors-issue-in-angular-8-without-changing-the-backend)

Comment: Won't Proxying to the backend server work only in development  and not in production

Comment: There are two ways to resolve CORS errors: 1) serve frontend and the API you are querying at the same host  2) enable CORS at the backend. If you go with a proxy, it's again one of the two: Either your frontend is served from the same host has your proxy, or your proxy (which acts as backend target for the frontend) has to have CORS enabled.

Comment: @Patiee You are right, proxying will only work in development. To make it work in Production, the backend would need to enable CORS. I thought you are practicing in local and backend is not in your control, hence suggested proxy :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do i do that @derpirscher

Comment: That depends on what you are using as backend. With heroku you are (probably) using nodejs and express, so [this](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)  is the way to go. If the backend isn't under your control, the only way is using a proxy.

Comment: The backend isn't in my control , but on using proxy will my website work in production ? @derpirscher

Comment: @Siddhant Why would you think, a proxy will only work for development? If by "proxy" you just mean the builtin proxy service from the angular `ng serve` you are right. But what keeps anyone from running a proxy on a service like heroku as well and then just pointing the production deployment also to that proxy?

Comment: @derpirscher I agree with your comments where you have mentioned two approaches, including the running of a proxy on a service like heroku. In my initial comment I had provided the link for Angular proxy (devServer proxy) and follow up comment was for the same.